# Verb agreement when using To Infinitive after ordinal numbers as subject

Tags: verb-agreement, infinitives, ordinal-numbers

I know that after ordinal numbers (the first, the second etc.) we can use to-infinitive clause. E.g:

> Ethan was the last person to understand the joke.

My questions is when the above construction acts as the subject of a sentence. Consider this:

> Plant scientists have been trying for years to genetically modify
> flowers for aesthetic purposes. **The first to go on sale** `were` blue
> carnations produced by Florigene of Melbourne, Australia, in 1996.

What is the criterion for choosing *were* after the infinitive? (is it in agreement with *the first* or *the first [flowers]*)

The sentence is taken from: https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg20126952-000-valentines-day-special-say-it-with-flowers/#ixzz726Lu0bW6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what is known as synesis, or [notional agreement](https://www.visualthesaurus.com/cm/wc/agreeing-to-disagree-why-we-use-notional-agreement/).

It’s “sense over syntax”; the meaning rules the subject-verb agreement.

Compare:

> *Plant scientists have been trying for years to genetically modify **flowers** for aesthetic purposes. The first [**modified flowers**] to go on sale **were** blue carnations produced by Florigene of
> Melbourne, Australia, in 1996.*

and:

> *Plant scientists have been trying for years to genetically modify **the carnation** for aesthetic purposes. The first [**modified carnation**] to go on sale **was** the blue carnation produced by
> Florigene of Melbourne, Australia, in 1996.*

Comment: What part of speech is 'first' here? Does a further deletion (of the to-infinitival clause:  'The first was/were ...') make a significant difference to agreement?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: The deletion of the *to*-infinitive clause would not make a difference in agreement, at least in this case. For “part of speech,” check in with your preferred source. An ordinal adjective? A pronoun? For the “part of the sentence,” the subject functions “like a noun.” Sorry for all the quote marks, but the labels themselves are ... “subjective.”